# Изменение координат картинки

Tags: delphi, изображения

Есть изображение карты, например Англии. Пользуясь компонентом `Image`, как сделать чтобы при `OnMouseUp` передавая новые координаты `X, Y` (ShiftState) изменить координаты изображения? Точно как в Google Maps, только без масштабирования: изменить местоположение, передвигать мышкой.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ну если вы имеете ввиду передвижение картинки по компоненту TImage мышкой, то это можно сделать, например, так:

```
var bmp:TBitMap;  // картинка, загружаемая в компонент TImage

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);  // здесь первоначальная загрузка
begin
bmp:=Tbitmap.Create;
bmp.LoadFromFile('yourImage.bmp');
// загружаем картинку( можно и в другом событии)
image1.Canvas.Draw(0,0,bmp); 
end;

procedure TForm1.Image2MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
if ssleft in shift then // если нажата левая кнопка мыши, то...
begin
// очищаем канву от ранее загруженного рисунка
PatBlt(image1.Canvas.Handle,0,0,image1.ClientWidth,image1.ClientHeight,WHITENESS);
// перерисовываем канву с новыми координатами рисунка
image1.Canvas.Draw(x,y,bmp);
end;
```

**P.S**

Пожалуйста, не мешайте все в одну кучу: Google Maps, Delphi, рисунки и из движение по канве. Вы этим очень запутываете людей. Достаточно просто правильно сформировать свой вопрос...